# symfony: How to translate a text that contains <p></p>?

Tags: symfony1, translation

i want to translate this below:

```
<?php echo __(<<<EOM
<p>
For security reasons...
</p>
EOM
) ?>
```

So i create this translation unit:

```
<trans-unit>
<source>For security reasons...</source>
<target>Por razones de seguridad...</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The problem: it is not translated less than i remove the `<p> </p>` tags.

Any way to translate it keeping those tags?

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not only translating the string:

```
<p> 
<?php echo __("For security reasons...") ?>
</p>
```

Another solution would it be to include the <p> tags into the translation strings. I don't know the symphony translation technique but that is how it's done with gettext.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the tags and the newlines to the translation xml file. Keep in mind that to be xml-safe, you need to use &lt; and &gt;